# Get registered assets in web3 metamask

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, ether, ethers.js

In web3 we call `web3.eth.getAccounts()` or `window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })` to list the accounts in metamask, is there any specific method we could call to get the registered tokens/assets in metamask?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to get registered assets in MetaMask.

Your best bet is to have a token list for which you check balances from a blockchain after the user has connected the account.

Comment: Pretty vague suggestion - got a link to some sample code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get address info after get the address
please see the endpoint in https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-address-info

you can get ETH and other tokens info from this endpoint

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31883126)